# Пропустить первую запись в цикле foreach

Tags: php

Вывожу новости циклом `
Как можно пропустить первую запись и не выводить?

Comment: добавить флаг буленовскую переменную

Comment: лучше решите данный вопрос на этапе подготовки данных, при выборке из БД (`limit-offset`), либо в контроллере (в логике (`array_pop`)), а не на конечном этапе в представлении .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вариант 1.** 
Используйте `for` вместо `foreach` и начинайте проход по коллекции с певого элемента

```
        for (int $i = 1; $i < length; $i++)
        {
            //TODO
        }
```

**Вариант 2.**
Создайте булевую переменную и проверяйте ее не изменилась ли она.

```
            $flag = true;
            foreach ($collection as $value)
            {
                if ($flag)
                {
                    $flag = false;
                }
                else {
                    //TODO
                }
            }
```

**Вариант 3.** Удалите первый элемент из массива перед проходом по нему

```
unset($array[0]);
```

**Вариант 4.** Вообще не заполняйте коллекцию этим элементом еще на этапе формирования запроса к БД.

Comment: в цикле `for` проще начать с 1 без всяких `if`, вам не кажется?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, конечно проще :) Поправил