# Вывод в while кроме одного значения

Tags: php

Есть запрос в бд на вывод всех строк
Потом в цикле мы получаем все ид
Как сделать, чтобы он выводил все ид, кроме, например первого ид

```
while($row = $db->get_row($sql_cat))
{
    $cat .= $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: что возвращает `get_row`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну в самом простом случае:

```
while($row = $db->get_row($sql_cat))
{
    if($row['id'] == 15) {
       continue;
    }

    $cat .= $row['id'];
}
```

Документация: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.continue.php

Обратите внимание: напрямую так делать в реальных приложениях не всегда хорошо, т.к. фактически хардкодится некоторая константа и не всегда вывод начинается с id =1 или id = 15, более правильно будет привести код к следующему виду:

```
$is_first_row = true;
while($row = $db->get_row($sql_cat))
{
    if($is_first_row) {
       $is_first_row = false;
       continue;
    }

    $cat .= $row['id'];
}
```

Также если вы работаете с базой -- то вы могли бы и на более раннем этапе (при составлении запроса к базе) отфильтровать это значение. Оно вряд ли бы сильно сэкономило бы ресурсы, просто для общего понимания. Вы же работаете с MySql? Почитайте про LIMIT и OFFSET.

Вариант с if помогает пропустить любую строку (в начале, в середине) или несколько строк с любым условием. Используя LIMIT+OFFSET вы сможете пропустить первую строку, в середине не получится. Плюс, я подозреваю, что вы хотите вывести "**все**, кроме первой" -- а [для этого нужно задать заведомо большое число](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/255517/mysql-offset-infinite-rows). Вообще это "все" в реальных приложениях редко нужно, обычно ставят пагинацию...

Плюс, почитайте для общего понимания вот этот вопрос: [Пропустить первую запись в цикле foreach](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594388/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5-foreach) - там описаны варианты для других циклов.

Comment: Минус за "кастыль" if не самый лучший вариант для этого, тем более так как написали его вы.

Comment: @Naumov Что именно вам не нравится и какой вариант предлагаете?

Comment: `if (id==15)` удалил я запись и первой стала 16, и алгоритм рухнул. А вот про лимит вы правы так что стоит спросить у автора, какой запрос? и после ответить.

Comment: @Naumov А, теперь я понял, про что вы говорите. Действительно, поленился. Дополнил ответ.